# is there any tool to calculate energy consumption of each core of the processor?

Tags: linux, cpu

I am working on a project in which I am changing the speed of the CPU according to the load on the CPU. I am trying to implement this for the single core of the processor. Thus, I need a tool which can show me how much energy a CPU core is using.

There are a number of tools available which can calculate the energy consumption of the whole CPU, but I want to see energy used by a particular core of the processor.

Comment: A ammeter should do - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter

Comment: I need a tool like powertop and powerstat.

Answer (score 0):

The closest tool I can think of is [PowerTop](https://01.org/powertop/), but as far as I know, it provides some estimates about power consumption, not the exact value.

Comment: Yes, it is right. But it estimates the result for the whole processor. It does not give the estimated result for each core of the CPU.